# How to reference a class from child to parent?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

It may sound stupid but how can i reference a class from one script in child in another script in parent? I cant find anything on google. Note: There are couple errors in my script, that's not the point of the post.

[image]

```
//Public

//Private
private Rigidbody myRigidbody;
private Renderer myRenderer;
private Material tileDefaultMaterial;
private Material tileSelectedMaterial;
private Material tileSameGroupMaterial;

void Start () {
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    myRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
    tileDefaultMaterial = Resources.Load ("TileDefault", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    tileSelectedMaterial = Resources.Load ("TileSelected", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    tileSameGroupMaterial = Resources.Load ("TileSameGroup", typeof(Material)) as Material;
}

void Update () {
    
}

public class TileClass {
    
    public int tileGroup = 0; //Indicates the Tile Group Number.

}
```

[image]

```
//Public
public GameObject[] allTiles; //Aray of all Tile GameObject.
public bool tileIsSelected = false; //If a Tile is Selected.
public int selectedTileGroup = 0; //Indicates the Selected Tile Group Number.
public int tileGroup = 0; //Indicates the Tile Group Number.



//Private


void Start () {

    allTiles = new GameObject[transform.childCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++){
        allTiles [i] = transform.GetChild (i).gameObject;
    }
}

void Update () {

}

void OnMouseDown (){

    RaycastHit hitInfo = new RaycastHit ();
    bool hit = Physics.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition), out hitInfo);

    if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject.tag == "Tile" && tileIsSelected == false) {
        Debug.Log ("A Tile is Selected!");
        tileIsSelected = true;
        selectedTileGroup = ;
        for(int i = 0; i < allTiles.Length; i++){
            if (this.tileGroup == selectedTileGroup) {
                allTiles [i].GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = tileSameGroupMaterial;
            }
        }
        myRenderer.material = tileSelectedMaterial;
    } else if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject.tag == "Tile" && tileIsSelected == true) {
        Debug.Log ("Second Tile is Clicked! (Should Swap them!)");
        myRenderer.material = tileDefaultMaterial;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do that. Your class is already inheriting from MonoBehaviour.

What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please do not provide code as images. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: I want to create a class with some variables for each tile and then manage them from the manager script. I am not sure if that's the best way to do it. I am new to C# and Unity.

Comment: Yes you can and that's fine. check Umair M's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40546965/3785314).

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a famous saying :

```
var allTiles = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Tile>();
```

And as I told you yesterday, Add `OnMouseDown()` in Tile.cs and write `myRenderer.material = tileDefaultMaterial;` there. No need to write this in TileManager.cs. And NO need to use `Raycast` when using `OnMouseDown()`.

Comment: I tried having my code in Tile.cs but i cant manage things like tileIsSelected or selectedTileGroup because I have this script in all of my tiles. For example if i select a tile and then i click on empty space, i want tileIsSelected to be false on all tiles or when i click on a tile with group number 1, i want to change the material on all tiles with same group number. I thing it should be easier to do that if i had the code in TileManager.cs.

Comment: That makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I can't read your image code, so I'll make up my own class names for the example. I'll call the parent class `TileManager` and the child class `Tile`.

Say in `Tile` you want access to the array of tiles in the `TileManager`. If `allTiles` is declared as public, you'd do in `Tile` somewhere.

```
TileManager tileManager = transform.parent.GetComponent<TileManager>();
var allTiles = tileManager.allTiles;
```

Now the `Tile` child has a reference to the array. Was this what you were wanting?

Answer (score -4):

how about base.Method?

That should do it

Comment: I don't think this is an inheritance question - he's talking about the parent/child relationships in the Unity transform hierarchy.