# How to manage variables in child script from another script in parent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to manage some variables in TileScript like TileGroupID, TileIsSelected from the TilesManager script in parent but i cant find a way to do it. For example i want to search all the Tiles if one of them have TileIsSelected True and then do something in all Tiles that have TileGroupID 1. I created tilesArray to keep track all the game objects but i don't know how i can use that to do what i said earlier.

[image]

[image]

TileScript:

```
//Public
public int tileGroupID = 0; //Indicates the Tile Group ID.
public bool tileIsSelected = false; //If this Tile is Selected.
public GameObject[] tilesArray; //Reference to Tiles Array.

//Private
private Rigidbody myRigidbody;
private Renderer myRenderer;
private Material tileDefaultMaterial;
private Material tileSelectedMaterial;
private Material tileSameGroupMaterial;

void Start () {
    tilesArray = GetComponentInParent<TilesManager> ().tilesArray;
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    myRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
    tileDefaultMaterial = Resources.Load ("TileDefault", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    tileSelectedMaterial = Resources.Load ("TileSelected", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    tileSameGroupMaterial = Resources.Load ("TileSameGroup", typeof(Material)) as Material;
}
```

TilesManager:

```
//Public
public GameObject[] tilesArray; //Aray of all Tiles GameObject.

//Private


void Start () {
    tilesArray = new GameObject[transform.childCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++){
        tilesArray [i] = transform.GetChild (i).gameObject;
    }
}

void OnMouseDown (){

    //Do stuff with each tile.
}
```

Comment: The tile must haveTileIsSelected True and then do something in all Tiles that have TileGroupID 1. What do you mean by this? The tile must be both select and have TileGroupID value of 1 for something to be done to it?

Comment: For example when i click on a tile TileIsSelected change to true, change his material and change all the other tile material that have same TileGroupID as the one i clicked.

Comment: Ok. Is `OnMouseDown ()` is being called at this moment?

Comment: I have couple lines in OnMouseDown a Ray cast and some code to change materials on different situations but it has errors because as i said i dont know how to check all the tiles which one has TileIsSelected true and which tiles have TileGroupID 1,2,3. If i change the material now it changes the material for all tiles because the code is in all of them. myRenderer.material = tileSelectedMaterial; I want to be able to change only some of them.

Comment: I didn't make clear what i wanted to do and i didn't get the answers i expected(They did help me but my question wasn't what i had in mind) so i decide to make a new one with more specific question and this time i got exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnMouseDown` function should be moved from the `TilesManager` script to the `TileScript` script. It will be called when each Tile is clicked on. When this happens, you can call a function on the `TilesManager` function and pass it the current GameObject that was clicked on.

In your `TileScript` script:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    //Let Tiles Manager know that there was a press on (this) Tile
    tileManagerInstance.OnObjectSelection(this.gameObject);
}
```

In your `TilesManager` script:

```
public void OnObjectSelection(GameObject selectedObj)
{
//Change Material of the Selected GameObject
    selectedObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = tileSelectedMaterial;
}
```

> when i click on a tile TileIsSelected change to true, change his
>   material and change all the other tile material that have same
>   TileGroupID as the one i clicked.

All you need now is a basic `for` loop. Loop through the `tilesArray` array and check which one has the-same `tileGroupID` as the GameObject that was clicked.

```
void findTheSameTileGroupIDAndChangeColor(GameObject selectedObj)
{
    //Get the TileScript attached to the selectedObj
    TileScript selectedTileScript = selectedObj.GetComponent<TileScript>();

    //Loop through all GameObject in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < tilesArray.Length; i++)
    {
        /* 
           Make sure this is NOT selectedObj since we've arleady 
           changed its Material in OnObjectSelection function
        */
        if (selectedObj != tilesArray[i])
        {
            //Get TileScript attached to the current Tile loop
            TileScript tileLoop = tilesArray[i].GetComponent<TileScript>();
            //Check if selectedObj and the current loop tileGroupID matches
            if (selectedTileScript.tileGroupID == tileLoop.tileGroupID)
            {
                //It matches! Now, change it's color
                tileLoop.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = tileSelectedMaterial;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally the Whole thing I said put together:

*TileScript*:

```
public class TileScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int tileGroupID = 0; //Indicates the Tile Group ID.
    public bool tileIsSelected = false; //If this Tile is Selected.
    public GameObject[] tilesArray; //Reference to Tiles Array.

    //Private
    private Rigidbody myRigidbody;
    private Renderer myRenderer;
    private Material tileDefaultMaterial;
    private Material tileSelectedMaterial;
    private Material tileSameGroupMaterial;

    private TilesManager tileManager;

    void Start()
    {
        tilesArray = GetComponentInParent<TilesManager>().tilesArray;
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        myRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        tileDefaultMaterial = Resources.Load("TileDefault", typeof(Material)) as Material;
        tileSelectedMaterial = Resources.Load("TileSelected", typeof(Material)) as Material;
        tileSameGroupMaterial = Resources.Load("TileSameGroup", typeof(Material)) as Material;

        //Get Tiles Manager
        GameObject tileManagerObj = GameObject.Find("Tiles");
        tileManager = tileManagerObj.GetComponent<TilesManager>();
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        //Let Tiles Manager know that there was a press on (this) Tile
        tileManager.OnObjectSelection(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

*TilesManager:*

```
public class TilesManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] tilesArray; //Aray of all Tiles GameObject.
    public Material tileSelectedMaterial;

    void Start()
    {
        tilesArray = new GameObject[transform.childCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            tilesArray[i] = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
        }
    }

    //Will be called from  the TileScript(Receives any tile that is selected)
    public void OnObjectSelection(GameObject selectedObj)
    {
        //Change Material of the Selected GameObject
        selectedObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = tileSelectedMaterial;

        //Change Mateial of other GameObjects that matches the  tileGroupID of the selectedObj
        findTheSameTileGroupIDAndChangeColor(selectedObj);
    }

    void findTheSameTileGroupIDAndChangeColor(GameObject selectedObj)
    {
        //Get the TileScript attached to the selectedObj
        TileScript selectedTileScript = selectedObj.GetComponent<TileScript>();

        //Loop through all GameObject in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < tilesArray.Length; i++)
        {
            /* 
               Make sure this is NOT selectedObj since we've arleady 
               changed its Material in OnObjectSelection function
            */
            if (selectedObj != tilesArray[i])
            {
                //Get TileScript attached to the current Tile loop
                TileScript tileLoop = tilesArray[i].GetComponent<TileScript>();
                //Check if selectedObj and the current loop tileGroupID matches
                if (selectedTileScript.tileGroupID == tileLoop.tileGroupID)
                {
                    //It matches! Now, change it's color
                    tileLoop.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = tileSelectedMaterial;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to tell OP in his previous 2 questions.

Comment: Just [noticed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40546965/3785314) that. In this case, OP should follow simple Unity project. I don't think that he should watch one of the Unity [projects](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials). This should give him ideas of how to structure scripts.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I was trying to find a way to make this the last 2 days. Also big thanks to Umair M. One small mistake in the code. selectedObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = tileSelectedMaterial; is wrong it should be tileLoop.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = tileSelectedMaterial;

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that but put `Debug.Log("1")` inside `if (selectedObj != tilesArray[i])`. It should actually be called how many amount of stuff there is in the `tilesArray` array minus 1(the object that was clicked). Looks like you fixed it. You are welcome! I just saw the typo and it is now fixed.